# How to multiple encoding parameters for put method Alamofire Request

Tags: swift, alamofire

My request link is this : `http://et.net/webservice/put/profile?api_key=[K]&m=[M]&profile={"birthday":"1994-01-01", "gender":"MALE", "marital":"SINGLE"}`

`api_key` and `m` is url value and `profile` as JSON

```
    let parameters: Parameters = ["api_key": apiKey,
                                  "m": mobile,
                                  "profile": ["birthday":"",
                                              "gender": "Male",
                                              "marital": "Single"]]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you read the docs?

Comment: use 'parameters' does not accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want those in your URL, you're going to have to percent-encode them. You can do this using `URLComponents`.

So, build your JSON string however you want:

```
let dictionary = [
    "birthday": "1994-01-01",
    "gender": "MALE",
    "marital": "SINGLE"
]
let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(dictionary)
let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
```

Then you can build the URL and perform the request:

```
let urlString = "http://et.net/webservice/put/profile"

var components = URLComponents(string: urlString)!
components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "api_key", value: "[K]"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "m", value: "[M]"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "profile", value: jsonString)
]

Alamofire.request(components.url!, method: .put)
    .response { response in
         // do whatever you want
}
```

---

If you were building a `.post` request, you could let Alamofire encode this into the body of the request for you:

```
let parameters = [
    "api_key": "[K]",
    "m": "[M]",
    "profile": jsonString
]

Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
    .response { response in
        // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: You're right. Alamofire puts those in the body of the request. You want it in the URL for a `.put` request. So, use `URLComponents` to percent-encode this for you. See revised answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48660345/how-to-post-parameter-with-plus-sign-in-alamofire please see my question

Comment: I have blood parameter in JSON dictionary, when post (Plus +) bloods does not accept