# How to post parameter with (+ plus sign) in Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

when post `A+` or `O+` or any (+) bloods types with `+` character, I receive a "not valid blood" error.

The `blood` value is in `JSON` dictionary: How do I post `+` character in Alamofire?

```
let dictionary = ["fname": "name",
                  "lname": "family",
                  "blood": "A+"]

let updateData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(dictionary)
let jsonString = String(data: updateData, encoding: .utf8)!

var components = URLComponents(string: registerUrl)!
components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "api_key", value: apiKey),
    URLQueryItem(name: "profile", value: jsonString)
]

Alamofire.request(components.url!, method: .post).responseJSON {
    response in
    if response.result.isSuccess {
        let json: JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
        print(json)
    }
}
```

Comment: apply percent-encoding to your UrlString.

Comment: how to apply percent encoding?

Comment: I think problem is in json dictionary

Comment: `guard let encodedURL = components.url!.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed) else {
            print("unhelpful message")
            return nil
        }`

Comment: @Rocky - Unfortunately, `.urlQueryAllowed` will allow the `+` to pass unescaped, although most web services require it to be. (Besides, `addingPercentEncoding` is a `String` method, not a `URL` method.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `URLComponents` will not percent encode `+` character although many (most?) web services require it to be (because, pursuant to the `x-www-form-urlencoded` spec, they replace `+` with space character). When I posted bug report on this, Apple's response was that this was by design, and that one should manually percent encode the `+` character:

```
var components = URLComponents(string: "https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/")!

components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "i", value: "1+2")
]

components.percentEncodedQuery = components.percentEncodedQuery?.replacingOccurrences(of: "+", with: "%2B")
```

Obviously, if you were doing a standard `application/json` request, with the JSON in the body of the request, no such percent encoding is needed. But if you're going to include the JSON in the URL like this, then you will have to percent encode the `+` character yourself.

---

Alternatively, you can let Alamofire do this for you:

```
let parameters = [
    "api_key": apiKey,
    "profile": jsonString
]

Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in
    ...
}
```

This, admittedly puts the properly percent encoded value in the body of the `POST` request, not the URL as in your example, but generally in `POST` requests, that's what we want.